# Proving a decreasing, convergent sequence.

Tags: proof-writing

Let $t_1=4$ and $t_{n+1}= \sqrt{3+2t_n}$. 
How do I prove that $3<t_{n+1}<t_n$? 
I understand that it is true, but I don't understand how to show it...

Thanks!

Comment: The proofs are by induction.

Comment: Hint: suppose $t_n=3+\epsilon$ for some positive $\epsilon$, then...

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that t_1 = 4 > 3.

Assuming $ t_k > 3 $, then

$ t_{k+1}^2 = 3 + 2t_k > 3 + 2 \times 3 > 9 $

That implies $ t_{k+1} > 3 $

By principle of mathematical induction, $ t_n > 3 $ for all $ n \ge 1 $

After establishing the fact above, we can prove $ t_n > t_{n-1} $ easily as follow:

$ t_n > t_{n+1}         $

$ t_n > \sqrt{3 + 2t_n} $

$ t_n^2 > 3 + 2t_n      $

$ t_n^2 - 2t_n  > 3     $

$ t_n^2 - 2t_n + 1 > 4  $

$ (t_n- 1)^2 > 4        $

$ (t_n- 1) > 2          $

$ t_n > 3               $

Of course, you read this backwards!

Comment: What about showing that $t_n\gt t_{n+1}$?

Comment: The solution is edited to include the proof for $ t_n > t_{n+1} $

Comment: Andrew - you are awesome! Proof by induction when the hypothesis is an inequality has befuddled me... until now. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to note that, if $t>3$, then $3<\sqrt{3+2t}<t$.

The first inequality proves all terms in the sequence are $>3$, the second inequality proves the sequence is decreasing.